# We're seeing "corrupted" opcache on our servers. Any idea how to resolve?

Tags: php, opcache

We're seeing an odd issue that I've been struggling to resolve.

Every now and then we do a deploy to our servers, and one server will start streaming errors into the logs along the lines of,

```
require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/CrrrectPath/Abstract.php' 
(include_path='/var/www/') in /var/www/CorrectPath/Object.php on line 2
```

The issue is not always an `include()`. Sometimes a method name gets corrupted in the same way (a single character being replaced with another character).

Having debugged an affected server in production, I can see the files themselves are absolutely fine. My gut here is that the opcache of the files is getting corrupted in some way.

We had "validate_timestamps" enabled, so I figured it was plausible that the files were being re-read mid `rsync` (we r-sync from one folder to the "live" folder as part of our deploy). We then disabled "validate_timestamps" and are now doing a `opcache_reset()` when the code has been fully rsynced. The issue does happen less frequently, but we're still seeing occurrences.

Has anyone else come across this issue? Any suggestions for a resolution (other than completely changing how we deploy)?

For info,

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.0.21-1~ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jul  6 2017 09:38:10) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.21-1~ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's random but - `Failed opening required '/var/www/CrrrectPath/Abstract.php` - is it a `typo`? Second letter of `CrrrectPath` it's and `r` not an `o` ?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos That isn't a typo. That's the actual problem, and the error we get. Hence I believe the opcache for the file is getting corrupted or something.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this issue is/is similar to the following PHP bug,

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71135

We're re-enabling "validate_timestamps" and **not** doing `opcache_reset()` on deploy. Hopefully this will resolve the issue.

Comment: Did it resolve the issue? we're still having similar issues, running Ubuntu 18.4 + PHP 7.3.3